# Use struct or pointer to struct if they are the same size?

Tags: c, optimization, memory, struct

I am writing a program and to simplify some of my function declarations I created a utility struct, lets call it `Foo`.

`Foo` simply contains two enum values, each of which only have two possible values, giving us only four possible forms of `Foo` that will ever be passed to these functions. The internals of a `Foo` is never changed during the use of a function, they are only accessed, so I created four static constants for these possibilities and simply pass them by value to each function.

I understand that passing a struct by value to a function means each of its members will be copied and pushed onto the stack with each function call, so, seeing as these structs are constant, I could pass pointers to them to the functions and simply read the values that way. This also let me use some modern syntax like `static const Foo *A = &(Foo)...`, which I felt pretty happy about.

My issue is, at least on my platform, `sizeof(Foo)` and `sizeof(Foo*)` are both the same: 8, so I don't know if this would actually be any better in the end. The memory usage would be the same, and I don't know if the copying associated with pushing the values onto the stack would be greater or worse than the dereferencing associated with passing the pointers.

I also considered that I could declare the enum members of `Foo` as `uint8_t` instead, which would enforce that they should be of size 1 rather than size 4 as it appears they are now, or I could even make the entire `Foo` a `uint8_t` and use the last two bits for the enum values, but I fear that those options may harm the readability of my code too much. (Not to mention, the two enums used within `Foo` are also used externally, separate from each other, so this may require me to refactor that somewhat as well).

If it is of any importance, it is much more important that this program be optimized for memory usage rather than speed. The size of the stack is not limited, but the overall memory footprint is the main concern, rather than speed.

EDIT: By request, here is some code,

Here are the types:

```
typedef enum { A = 0, B = 1 } Bar;
typedef enum { C = 0, D = 1 } Baz;
typedef struct {
    Bar r;
    Baz z;
} Foo;
```

And I am wondering if which of these approaches is better:

Pass by value,

```
static const Foo foo0 = { .r=0; .z=0 };
static const Foo foo1 = { .r=1; .z=0 };
static const Foo foo2 = { .r=0; .z=1 };
static const Foo foo3 = { .r=1; .z=1 };
void func(const Foo f);
```

Pass by reference,

```
static const Foo *foo0 = &(Foo){ .r=0; .z=0 };
static const Foo *foo1 = &(Foo){ .r=1; .z=0 };
static const Foo *foo2 = &(Foo){ .r=0; .z=1 };
static const Foo *foo3 = &(Foo){ .r=1; .z=1 };
void func(const Foo *f);
```

Comment: Most compilers pass arguments in registers these days. By passing a structure by value it might not be possible.

Comment: You did a good job of describing the code. But you know the saying "a picture is worth a thousands words". For us is "code is worth a thousands words". So it help a lot to actually show the code you are talking about.

Comment: What is specifically  "_modern syntax_" about `static const Foo *A = &(Foo)...`?.  In maintenance might this structure be expanded such that your perceived optimisation no longer applies? Better perhaps to use one idiom throughout.  Either way, a pointer may be passed in  single register, regardless of compiler optimisation.  The structure is unlikely to be passed in that way - possibly with optimisation, but it is non-deterministic.  If you want to know, test it at https://godbolt.org/ for your compiler and optimisation settings.

Comment: @bolov i added some examples, hope it helps!

Comment: When you pass pointers, you don't need to make the actual variables pointers. Use the pointer-to operator `&` to pass a pointer to a structure (or any named variable). E.g. `static const Foo foo0 = { .r=0; .z=0 }; func(&foo0);` will work just fine.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I wasn't aware of the differences in register usage. If that is the case, then the difference may be more obvious than I thought!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, that is also true, but I don't think that affects the question, no? That just changes the syntax of the const definitions.

Comment: It is in any event a micro-optimisation at best.  If you write clear idiomatic code, the compiler optimiser will likely do a better job _holistically_ than you will achieve by worrying about such minutiae.  You should concentrate on an intrinsically efficient design, and let the compiler worry about the code generation.  That will likely have greater benefit.

Comment: Noting that the optimiser can reduce _code size_ considerably, but may have little impact on data size, since these wil be whatever they are.  Some compilers insert guard space between data objects to detect overrun for example, so optimisation may look like it has had a data size benefit, but in fact the debug padding has just been omitted.

Comment: @Clifford of course! My professors always say micro optimization is stupid and I agree, but this was more a curiousity as I couldn't see an obvious difference with my level of knowledge. I checked the code with godbolt and it does appear that the pointer results in much fewer instructions.

Comment: Curiosity satisfied then.

Comment: ... ah, since you added examples it seems the "_modern_" part was in the `...`.  the part you actually stated was nothing new.

Comment: Avoiding pointers that are not *logically* needed is a win. It is not optimisation in any way, shape, or form. It is keeping the code simple. If it logically makes sense to pass it by value, then pass it by value, *even if there is a slight performance loss*.

Comment: @Clifford "The structure is unlikely to be passed in that way - possibly with optimisation, but it is non-deterministic." Nonsense.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI care to elaborate? I meant that without specification of the compiler, version, target and compiler settings used we cannot determine how it might treat the code.

Comment: @Clifford Compilers that want to be on the market for longer than 30 seconds follow *platform calling conventions*.  They are normally independent of compiler versions, compiler settings and compiler manufacturer, so you need not worry about any of those.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI  I appreciate the explanation.  Could the compiler not either instantiate a copy of the structure on the stack and pass a pointer to the stack in the register (as presumably it would have to for a larger structure), or pass a copy of the structure in the register if it were small enough?  My point is that both could be be ABI compliant, but since structures are not often that small, one might use a single common method unless optimisation were applied.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI ... looking at clang ARMv7 I see that each structure member uses a separate register for each member for small structures - so I accept your point.

Comment: @Clifford You cannot have the compiler choose calling conventions depending on optimisations applied. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to link separately produced objects in one program. Passing small structs in registers and larger ones on the stack is normal, but in this case the ABI specifies which size goes where and everyone must obey it, regardless of optimisation levels, or chaos will quickly ensue.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI agreed.

Answer (score 3):

Small constant structures can definitely be passed by value instead of by reference (passing a pointer to some local or global object).  For modern ABIs, small structures (one or 2 words) are passed (and returned) in registers, so it is very efficient.

In your case, instead of passing global objects, you should probably pass compound literals, constructed at the point of call.  This way, you avoid the overhead of accessing and/or copying the global objects.

You can use macros with meaningful names or explicit arguments to achieve this:

```
typedef enum { A = 0, B = 1 } Bar;
typedef enum { C = 0, D = 1 } Baz;

typedef struct {
    Bar r;
    Baz z;
} Foo;

#define FOO_AC  ((Foo){ .r=A, .z=C })
#define FOO_BC  ((Foo){ .r=B, .z=C })
#define FOO_AD  ((Foo){ .r=A, .z=D })
#define FOO_BD  ((Foo){ .r=B, .z=D })

#define FOO(R,Z)  ((Foo){ .r=(R), .z=(Z) })

void func(const Foo f);

[...]

int main() {
    func(FOO_AC);
    func(FOO_BC);
    func(FOO_AD);
    func(FOO_BD);
    // even more readable:
    func(FOO(A,C));
    func(FOO(B,C));
    func(FOO(A,D));
    func(FOO(B,D));
    return 0;
}
```